# $y''$ in terms of $y$ if $y=\cos^{-1}x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

> Find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ if $y=\cos^{-1}x$ in terms of $y$ only.

The solution is given as $y''=-\cot y.\csc^2y$, but is it the only solution ?

**My Attempt**

$$
y'=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\\y''=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}.(1-x^2)}.-2x=\frac{-x}{(1-x^2)^{{3}/{2}}}
$$
Here $y=\cos^{-1}x\implies x=\cos y$
$$
y''=\frac{-\cos y}{(\sin^2y)^{3/2}}=\frac{-\cos y}{|\sin y|^3}=\frac{-\cos y}{|\sin y|}.\frac{1}{\sin^2y}=\color{blue}{\pm\csc^2y.\cot y}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way:
$$x=\cos(y)$$
Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$:
$$1=-\sin(y)\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=-\frac{1}{\sin(y)}$$
Now differentiate again:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\cot(y)\csc(y)$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}=-\frac{1}{\sin(y)}\cot(y)\csc(y)$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}=-\frac{\cos(y)}{\sin^3(y)}$$
And [@Andreas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/317854/andreas) covered your sign error already, but a little bit of extension:

Osberve that $\text{ran}{(\cos^{-1})}=[0,\pi]$, and the $\sin(x)\geq 0$ iniqualits holds $\forall x \in [0, \pi]$, so you need to pick the positive root. But you can avoid it with using the method I've used.

Note: If you invert the $\cos$ on the interval $[-\pi, 0]$, then the $\sin$ will be negative (or 0) there, so you will need to choose the negative sine. But the usual way of inverting the cosine is on the $[0, \pi]$ interval.

Comment: ok we are only choosing $+\sin y$, but i'm really confused of why ?. could u pls comment on that ?

Comment: @ss1729 I added the answer to that question as well, check the end of my answer.

Comment: ohh thats right. its clear now and ur way is better in that way.

Comment: @ss1729 I added a small note, you might want to check that too.

Comment: u mean if i am only considering the principal value branch then $\sin y\geq 0$ as $y=\cos^{-1}x\in[0,\pi]$ right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But if you define $\cos^{-1}$ to return values from $[-\pi, 0]$, then the sin will be negative there.

Answer (score 1):

You are introducing an option of signs which does not exist. Start with your previous result here:

$$
y''=\frac{- x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}.(1-x^2)}
$$

Observe that the root is only the positive root (!) which is $+ \sin y$, so you get

$$
y''=\frac{-\cos(y)}{\sin^3(y)} = - \csc^2y.\cot y
$$

This is the only solution (apart from the usual angle shift properties of the trig functions).

Comment: thanx. but hw do u knw that $+\sin y$ is the only root ?

Comment: $\sqrt{}$ is always the positive root (only). Also, look back at how you derived your first equation. You have  $dx/dy = d(\cos(y))/dy = - \sin y = - \sqrt{1- \cos^2(y)}= - \sqrt{1- x^2}$. Here the root is positive only. Hence, taking the inverse, $dy/dx = - 1/ \sqrt{1- x^2}$ with the positive root only, and this continues into the following equations.

Answer (score 0):

$$x=\cos y,$$
$$1=-y'\sin y,$$
$$0=-y''\sin y-y'^2\cos y,$$

$$\color{green}{y''=-\frac{\cos y}{\sin^3y}}.$$